# How do I add my portable MinGW as a compiler in my portable VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw, portability

I have a portable version of VS Code on a USB stick as well as a copy of MinGW. But when i try to run a c file on VS Code, the MinGW copy on the USB stick does not show up as an option when running (only the ones I have on my C: and D: disks.

I've tried looking at c_cpp_properties.json but have no idea what to change
[image: the options that show up]

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw you should add `D:\mingw64\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.